# Set variable inside select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT   
    ft.id
    ,ft.date
    ,(SET @column = 
            CASE WHEN ft.a < 0 THEN 'Ok' END 
            CASE WHEN ft.b > 0 THEN 'NotOk' END
    ) AS 'Wrong sign in column ' + @column
FROM dbo.table AS ft
```

Why is this not working? I'm getting a syntax error and I can't see it.. I want to build the column selected depending on the conditions.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the variable in query you can directly use the content of variable.
Following query will give you the required result.

Also you can not use the variable without declaring it in sql.

```
SELECT  ft.nBranchId
      , ft.tmDate
      ,'Wrong sign in column ' +
        CASE WHEN ft.fDeposits < 0 THEN 'fDeposits'
             WHEN ft.fWithdrawals > 0 THEN 'fWithdrawals'
             WHEN ft.fPerformanceFee > 0 THEN 'fPerformanceFee'
             WHEN ft.fFixedFee > 0 THEN 'fFixedFee'
             WHEN ft.fDividend > 0 THEN 'fDividend'
             WHEN ft.fReinvestment < 0 THEN 'fReinvestment'
             WHEN ft.fThresholdRate < 0 THEN 'fThresholdRate'
             WHEN ft.fPerfFeeCumulated > 0 THEN 'fPerfFeeCumulated'
        END
      as ColumnName
FROM dbo.FundTransactions AS ft
```

Comment: It kind a works except for I'm getting "No column name"

Comment: You can give the alias name for that column. I have updated the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong... Try:

```
SELECT  ft.nBranchId
      , ft.tmDate
      ,'Wrong sign in column ' +
        CASE WHEN ft.fDeposits < 0 THEN 'fDeposits'
             WHEN ft.fWithdrawals > 0 THEN 'fWithdrawals'
             WHEN ft.fPerformanceFee > 0 THEN 'fPerformanceFee'
             WHEN ft.fFixedFee > 0 THEN 'fFixedFee'
             WHEN ft.fDividend > 0 THEN 'fDividend'
             WHEN ft.fReinvestment < 0 THEN 'fReinvestment'
             WHEN ft.fThresholdRate < 0 THEN 'fThresholdRate'
             WHEN ft.fPerfFeeCumulated > 0 THEN 'fPerfFeeCumulated'
        END
FROM dbo.FundTransactions AS ft
```